# Why are Elsa's eyebrows brown in Frozen?

Tags: character, frozen

I had always thought her eyebrows were a silver or grey color but at a closer look, I discovered that they were brown.

This is weird because her hair is a yellowy white color but the eyebrows are a way off.

Anna has brown hair and eyebrows, and when she was shot by Elsa they stayed brown while her hair turned white. Are Elsa's eyebrows unaffected and are the color that Elsa's hair would be if she never had the ice powers?

Comment: She's obviously a bottle blonde ;-)

Comment: They work separately ;)

Comment: I demand photo evidence of this conspiracy.

Comment: could be related to her powers. Anna's got a white streak in her hair after she was hit with them when she was little

Comment: Facial hair color is often different from "head" hair color. - https://www.quora.com/Can-someone-naturally-have-different-hair-and-eyebrow-colors

Comment: @Tetsujin This is probably the correct answer, in a sense.  I don't think she's a *true* bottle blonde, but the character design was probably undertaken with an eye towards maximizing audience identification with Elsa and Anna among female viewers.  There are simply more blondes with brown eyebrows in the target audience than there are blondes with blond eyebrows.

Answer (score 1):

Both of her parents and her grandfather have dark eyebrows and both Anna and Elsa have dark eyebrows from an early age (even before Elsa's hair turns white as a result of her ice powers developing). This appears to be a genetic trait of their family.

[image]

Note that this is perfectly normal in our mundane world.

> Genetically speaking, hair color is pretty complex. "The genes that
> determine hair color are so-called 'incomplete dominant hereditary
> traits.' This means that there isn't one single gene that's dominant
> over the rest, but all genes influence each other," Petra Haak-Bloem,
> specialist at the centre, tells me.
>
> The same genes can express themselves differently for anyone. That
> allows for lots of possibilities, one of which is that the color of
> your head hair differs from the color of your armpit hair, pubes, or
> beard.
>
> "Generally speaking, people inherit hair color not only from their
> parents, but also from their grandparents and earlier ancestors. So
> it's entirely possible that one distant ancestor had a hair color that
> suddenly appears again though a certain combination of genes—and that
> can be quite unexpected for parents," Haak-Bloem continued.
>
> <sub><sup>[Why Do So Many Men Have Red Beards But Not Red Hair?](https://www.vice.com/en/article/ezv38a/why-do-so-many-men-have-red-beards-but-not-red-hair)</sup></sub>